# Eclipse Plugin Development: Remove old Plugins from Experimental Instance

Tags: eclipse-plugin

When launching the Experimental Instance, I noticed that Eclipse keeps existing Plugin Views under Window->Show View->Other.

Is it possible to remove these?

Answer (score 0):

Start Eclipse using the `-clean` argument to clean up the caches, you might also want `-clearPersistedState`.

Comment: mmmm - I tried both of those but the old Plugins are still visible